# webpack configuration error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

I tried to configure web pack for reacts web app, it kept telling me to use 
`npm install -D webpack-cli` :

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^
```

when I did what it was asking me it gave me this error :

```
 C:\Users\Desktop\lazabre1>webpack-dev-server
C:\Users\Desktop\lazabre1\webpack.config.js:59
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
        ^
```

this is my webpack.config.js file :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'

    ],

    output: {

        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),

        filename: 'bundle.js'

    },

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]

};
```

I have 2 questions: first - how to solve this problem //
                     second - what is the difference between `npm install webpack` and `npm install webpack-cli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a configuration file written for Webpack 1 (I guess, by the use of the `module.loader` key and the `NoErrorsPlugin`) and using Webpack 4 (if you did not specify otherwise, and by the request to use the CLI which is not included by default anymore).

Upgrade your configuration by following the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options) and update the [`NoErrorsPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/no-emit-on-errors-plugin/).

The `webpack-cli` is a package to use webpack from the command-line tool (what you are trying to do).